# Как в C# создать массив charecode-ов из строки символов что мы ввели в консоль или создали заранее?

Tags: c#

Например `string str = "abcdefs";`
и мне нужен массив  в котором (каждый элемент соответствует символу в строке, по порядку.
`// "abcdefs" = {97,98,,99,100,101,102,115}`

Помогите от души!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так каждый символ в строке и так соответствует своему коду.

```
string str = "abcdefs";
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)str[i]);
}
```

```
97
98
99
100
101
102
115
```

Если нужно получить массив байт в ASCII (или UTF8) кодировке, то можно проще:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

Численно результат для этой строки будет тот же.

Comment: Лучший, спасибо от души!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "abcdefs";
var chars = str.ToCharArray();
var codes = chars.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", codes));
```

Допустим str очень большая и не хотим создавать новые массивы. Проведем рефакторинг кода:

```
string str = "abcdefs";
var result = str.Select(c => (int)c);
```

Comment: работает ) От души !!)

Comment: Строка и так массив, а значит `var chars = str.ToCharArray();` не нужно, как, по сути, и `.ToArray()` (если нам строго не нужен массив). В итоге получаем `var codes = "abcdefs".Select(c => (int)c);`.

Comment: Здесь все ок, только `.ToCharArray()` лишнее. И `.ToArray()` наверное тоже. В `Join` не обязательно передавать именно массив.

Comment: спасибо за коментарии, вторая строка лишняя. только строка - это не массив, а IEnumerable. ToArray() вставил, т.к. было пожелание получить массив.

Comment: Начали использовать Linq - используйте со смыслом. А смысл в аккуратном коде и низком расходе памяти без создания лишних коллекций. А здесь целых 2 лишних массива. Ответ вы кстати можете отредактировать.